# List of long-Term Support & Resistance in forex or stocks

Tags: programming, historical-data, algorithmic-trading, technical-analysis, technicals

I'm looking for a study of historic long-Term Support & Resistance in forex or stocks.
If possible with their level of strength (strong, medium...).

Example

```
EURUSD Long-Term Support & Resistance
+---------------+-------------+------------------------------+
| PRICE LEVEL   | IMPACT      | YEAR                         |
+---------------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 1.6000-1.6040 | VERY STRONG | 2008                         |
| 1.5151        | STRONG      | 2009                         |
| 1.4941-1.4971 | STRONG      | 2011                         |
| 1.2425-1.2426 | STRONG      | Several years                |
| 1.2310-1.2370 | STRONG      | Several years                |
| 1.2100-1.2140 | STRONG+     | PERIODIC PIVOT (H/L) 1.21305 |
| 1.2035-1.2040 | AVERAGE     | 2012                         |
| 1.1603-1.1604 | STRONG-     | 1992                         |
| 0.8200-0.8230 | VERY STRONG | 2000                         |
+---------------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

As well, would you know any tools/program to calculate them automatically ?
Eg : EURUSD in weekly timeframe ?
Thank you.